# Usar variable plantilla con entero como parámetro no-tipo en bucle

Tags: c++, template

Tengo una variable plantilla que calcula *n-ésimo* término de la [sucesión de Fibonaci](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucesi%C3%B3n_de_Fibonacci):

```
#include <iostream>

fent_servir Nombre iguala sense_signe llarg acaba

plantilla ( Nombre I )
Nombre Fibonacci iguala
    Fibonacci obre I resta un tanca suma
    Fibonacci obre I resta dos tanca acaba

plantilla (          )
Nombre Fibonacci obre zero tanca iguala un acaba

plantilla (          )
Nombre Fibonacci obre un tanca iguala un acaba

sencer principal() inici
sortida_estandar injecta Fibonacci obre cinc tanca acaba
torna zero acaba fi
```

Esto produce como [salida](https://tio.run/##nVI9T8MwEJ3JrzipS6uqEhRYStsRiYW5W3V1nOiQY0f@YADx1wmXOLUjWhayxO/57t753om2XdVCdLNSVqQlVFL7o5P2nSwER7ouzjdUB1QIu0QohbYGZSYxTmohLZD2U8rJo6Oaz0EP/zJdosATwlPW0CQIPhOuCL4SaBVqT6w6PyzAy4axl9vDPgdY0oJaVNAg6UR7YzWClT7YTH5Ia@A2JBw03GVUGgfrDL2VDu4zFgGZgocJw8rwmDEneIRVnkJoEJYZGuupxGMfpUu04Hy52QgT/GQUb1Jwje02UebEohlyqkDYdzPWVqHkKzKO@8JmXxRTH19N02eOBk4NiRYOLhRFmi/MzykvsCjG4zOdjEbB9sQ6xU1mTIyNj@ZJxs76N/8Z1U84hl1RT98V9aHK4F5MH1/Fqv8plJq9KDOuctqp@SJuZ3Hh3dmpX6WHlZg@Me7h0Hrc@4q67ltUCmvXrXgDdmK5XOMP):

> ```
> 8
> ```

Como es de esperar. Pero [no puedo](https://tio.run/##nVM9T8MwEJ3rX3ESA62qSi0fCxRGJBZmturqONGhxK78wQDirxMucWJbfCw0Q/Oe795d7p3l6bRppOzPKlWTVlAr7Q9O2VeyEBzpRswn1ARsEe4S0bZoG2hNEeOUlsoCaV9STh0cNfwe9PhfpUOUeES4zTU0SYL3hGuCjwROLWpPXHX5vAKvOsZe7Z/vc4AlLemELXRIOtHeWI1glQ82k2/KGtiGhIOGXUaVcXCRobfKwWXGMiBTcFUwXBmuCwEVYLdNkPM9wiYPJXQI6wyN9VThYYjSFVpwvrq5kSb4YjIvSrLGfp8oc@QeMuRUiVBMg42ojc2zDk3H5nLddX/G7bah4nQyjj8Fu3shSuufTDeoT56XHkbXR@OESJbAck55hJWYXh/oaDRKdjTqiEVmTIyNg@Hhx@6HufwZNZgSw36pnn6/VB9VRsNj@vRVXPU/QqnZHzLT9qc1XK7iQguxGMxYzrdjzhxbildg0h7WJhLJLVqJxeLHgszr8K03mlubjs/5mZqLt6AoWVPff8q6xcb1G164O7leX@AX) ponerlo en un bucle:

```
sencer principal() inici

    per (sencer i iguala zero acaba i obre deu acaba augmenta i)
        sortida_estandar injecta Fibonacci obre i tanca injecta ' ' acaba

torna zero acaba fi
```

El error:

> ```
> error: the value of ‘i’ is not usable in a constant expression
>    sortida_estandar injecta Fibonacci obre i tanca injecta ' ' acaba
>                             ^
> note: ‘sencer i’ is not const
>   per (sencer i iguala zero acaba i obre deu acaba augmenta i)
> ```

Se queja de que `i` no es constante, pero no puede serlo porque necesito que el indizador del bucle aumente.

¿Cómo podría poner la plantilla `Fibonacci` en un bucle para, por ejemplo, mostrar los 20 primeros números de la sucesión?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien has dicho, no puedes usar un indizador no constante para pasarlo a la plantilla `Fibonacci`, eso es porque al ser plantilla, espera que el argumento sea conocido en tiempo de compilación.

Puedes solucionar tu problema generando un constructo iterable que pueda ser construido en tiempo de compilación, por ejemplo [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Yo te propongo un par de funciones:

1. Una función que reciba hasta que índice quieres la sucesión (y servirá para calcular el tamaño del `std::array`).
2. Una función auxiliar que cree un [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) y que llame a `Fibonacci` con cada elemento de la secuencia.

```
plantilla (Nombre I separa Nombre ... Index)
std::array obre Nombre separa I tanca auxiliar
    (const std::integer_sequence obre Nombre separa Index ... tanca &)
inici torna inici Fibonacci obre Index tanca ... fi acaba fi

plantilla ( Nombre I )
constexpr std::array obre Nombre separa I tanca Serie_Fibonacci() inici
    torna auxiliar obre I tanca (std::make_index_sequence obre I tanca()) acaba fi
```

Puedes usarlo [así](https://tio.run/##nVRNj9MwED03v2KklXYTlVbbBS6li7QXUC8cWIlrNHWcyJDYWceuyiL@OmESO45VuiCRSzwv4zcfbyasbVcVY/1VwUshOZRcmrzj@ig02E7IKpm@iMpijXAfgLpGXUGtIp@OS8Y1CGliqON5Jyo6Wzm@i/ARGR4Q3s0xpGACfgS7FPAzGG2N0giKmq7X6wwMbwgxfJfnXx7yh88fH/P8/eyshWSixRoaFDLARmmJoLmxegafuVZwa4NtJWxmq1Ad3M2m0byD17PNLBIEbyKEIsPbiIBb2NwG88kK@cxhE3kQpUFYzT2zDcJyNpU2osB88JIFauhMsd0yZU3UuK@cEcduFyB1oLRmk64yhKhBpFOp9CyFrRrSnuJGgXmLGuFVf0Ul1bYgPqE6KhcbIgqYJVWE@R5DqDUSkMTj9Ek1Q0p@juK5cJM0DkOSBJkhna7sIUv88YM4KImMpsTxJIsZUc7XdZNEdCUPzXzRaxDXuV2IHp4L0UeWcXDcdV8VRf0fopDs32hCM7ws3qZlgL0s@ClLxrkYW@9ovYf330@V2hPphTpZpEzJzrhxop3lFdck1pMdtvgiwxBmDOiYrrPEbaxbK3c@7/R4x/kPN2ml3daX4kWtx7T4qfWT/s@KHrkWPA@B08ylkixcXlPBk/TuUjpyN/iN52LI8axy75ZmWZSv/7@Fn0s6NYC2KbQTrVFwfYTteV6O2O@/TyLLksUf@z1t83E63cCNz8JVNA7elFbf/2JljVXXr6ike7Zc3uFv):

```
sencer principal()
inici per
    (const auto &v : Serie_Fibonacci obre quinze tanca ())
    sortida_estandar injecta v injecta ' ' acaba torna zero acaba fi
```